# SQL MAX() Function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I found a very interesting/strange thing about MAX() function in SQL.

I have column ID with varchar2(20) data type, having following entries:-
ID


 `1

 2

 3

 4

 5

 6

 9

 99

 909`

As per my understanding if i use "select max(ID) from table;" I should get 909 as the result but i get 99. Can somebody explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the column you are using MAX on is of type VARCHAR, it is going to sort the values based on a character-by-character evaluation.  It selects 99 because 9 > 0, and it will ignore the rest of the string.

Answer (score 11):

You have misunderstood - since the column is a varchar, not numeric, it is sorted by string values; `909` comes before `99`, so `99` is the maximum.

To see the maximum numeric value of your column, try:

```
select max(to_number(ID)) from my_table
```

Comment: Could you suggest SQL that would perform the conversion and yield the answer? Assuming that we can't always just change the database schema when we want to.

Comment: Can i please understand the mechanics... some reference would really help me.

Comment: @Namelus: `909` comes before `99`, just as `oily` comes before `oo` - is that any clearer?

Answer (score 4):

Your column is being represented as characters, not numbers.   So think of it as ordering these alphabetically.  Alphabetically 909 will come before 99 in ascending order.